# Laravel Group By relationship column

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I have `Invoice_Detail` model which handles all products and it's quantities, this model table `invoice_details` has `item_id` and `qty` columns.

The `Invoice_Detail` has a relation to `Items` model which holds all item's data there in its `items` table, which has `item_id`, `name`, `category_id`.

The `Item` model also has a relation to `Category` model which has all categories data in its `categories` table.

Question: I want to select top five categories from `Invoice_Detail`, how?

Here's what I did:

```
$topCategories = InvoiceDetail::selectRaw('SUM(qty) as qty')
    ->with(['item.category' => function($query){
        $query->groupBy('id');
    }])
    ->orderBy('qty', 'DESC')
    ->take(5)->get();
```

But didn't work !!

```
[{"qty":"11043","item":null}]
```

Comment: define: didn't work

Comment: @Jerodev, check the edit.

Comment: So, what exactly is the result you want? Do you want the top 5 categories for a single Invoice?

Comment: @Jerodev, top 5 categories at all. for all invoices.

Answer (score 1):

```
Category::select('categories.*',\DB::raw('sum("invoice_details"."qty") as "qty"'))
        ->leftJoin('items', 'items.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->leftJoin('invoice_details', 'invoice_details.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
        ->groupBy('categories.id')
        ->orderBy('qty','DESC')
        ->limit(5)
        ->get();
```

This will return you collection of top categories.
Tested on laravel 5.5 and PostgreSQL.

**UPD:**
To solve this without joins you can add to Categories model this:

```
public function invoiceDetails()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Invoice_Detail::class, Item::class);
}
```

And to select top 5 categories:

```
$top = Category::select()->with('invoiceDetails')
    ->get()->sortByDesc(function($item){
        $item->invoiceDetails->sum('qty');
    })->top(5);
```

But first solution with joins will work faster.

Comment: Yes, this will work, but I need it without join, using "with" or eloquent collection.